# Module of $SU(2)$

Tags: group-theory, group-representations, complex-numbers

I've read that

> "$SU(2)$ is the group of transformations in 2-dimensional complex space."

What specifically are the two complex dimensions? Is one dimension the real axis and the other the imaginary axis? Or is each axis a complex number (perhaps magnitude of a complex number)?

Along these lines, if I consider the $j=\frac{1}{2}$ representation as in
$$e^{i\sum_{m=1}^{3}\alpha_m\sigma_m}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix},$$ where $\alpha_m$ are the three parameters of $SU(2)$ and $\sigma_m$ are the generators,
what are the meanings-- in terms of the two dimensional complex space-- of the components of the vector on which the group element acts?

If I then consider a $j>\frac{1}{2}$ representation, how does one reconcile the >2 components of the vector with $SU(2)$'s action on a 2-dimensional space?

Comment: Two complex dimensions is the space $\Bbb C \times \Bbb C$.

Comment: So one could imagine two axes, each representing the magnitude of a complex number? Or in $\Bbb C \times \Bbb C$ should one think of an $SU(2)$ rotation as adjusting the four real parameters (3 of them independent) of the two complex dimensions?

Comment: Complex numbers are more than just two reals. There is an algebraic structure there that needs to be preserved. Having said that, I think you are probably better of asking this in mathematics, since you still seem to have trouble with the basic algebraic definitions. Did you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am reasonably familiar with the information in that Wikipedia page. Perhaps I can rephrase the question: I believe $SU(2)$ will act on the eigenvectors of the diagonalized generator; can someone please relate those eigenvectors to the aforementioned two-dimensional complex space?

Comment: When you ask "What specifically are the two complex dimensions?", you seem to be suggesting that you think there is some preferred basis for ${\mathbb C}^2$.   But there isn't, any more than there is a preferred basis for ${\mathbb R}^2$.   You could as well ask "What specifically are the two real dimensions in ${\mathbb R}^2$?".  This question is as meaningless as that would be.

Comment: To elaborate further:  You ask what are the meanings of the components of the vector representation of an element of ${\mathbb C}^2$.  Answer:  That depends entirely on what basis you've chosen.   It's always better not to choose a basis at all if you can avoid it.

Comment: Thanks, WillO. Let's suppose I've diagonalized $\sigma_3$ in the $j=1/2$ representation. So, that generator is $\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1 && 0 \\ 0 && -1 \end{pmatrix}$. Could we interpret the two components of a vector on which that would act?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think there's a clear way to visualize it. It's a vector with complex components. You can turn it into a vector with 4 real components but that loses some structure.

Comment: Actually, there is the Poincare sphere, used to visualized polarized light (which has 2 complex components). But the visualization is quite complicated.

Answer (score 1):

A 2-dimensional vector space requires 2 basis vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ to span it.  These vectors should not be thought of as either real or complex *per se*.  Instead, for a real vector space arbitrary combinations $a v_1 + b v_2$, $a$ and $b$ real, are also in the space, while for a complex vector space $a$ and $b$ can be complex.

An illuminating example is the set of $n x n$ hermitian matrices, which form a real vector space: even though the matrix elements are complex, the scalar multipliers must be real to preserve the hermiticity.

The standard choice of basis vectors for $j=1/2$ is to diagonalize $\sigma_z$.  Then the orthonormal basis vectors:

- spin-up $\qquad |+\rangle = (1,0)^T$
- spin-down $\quad |-\rangle = (0,1)^T$

are eigenvectors of $\sigma_z$:

$$ \mathbf{\sigma \cdot \hat{z}} \, \,  |+\rangle \, \, = \sigma_z \, |+\rangle \, \, = \, \, |+\rangle \quad , \quad \mathbf{\sigma \cdot \hat{z}} \, \,  |-\rangle \, \, = - \, \, |-\rangle$$

These basis vectors (aka states) therefore correspond to spin in the +z and -z directions, respectively.  Any other state, such as a spin pointing in the +x direction, can be written as a *complex* linear combination of these basis states.  The matrices of SU(2) rotate the state vector in its 2-dimensional space.

For representations in higher (say $n$) dimensional vector spaces, each 2x2 matrix maps onto an $nxn$ matrix such that the multiplication tables are preserved (i.e. a homomorphism).

Answer (score 0):

$j=\frac{1}{2}$ representation is the fundamental representation of the group $SU(2)$.

$SU(2)$ is the group of $2\times 2$ Unitary matrices with determinant $+1$. The group $SU(2)$ does act on a two dimensional complex space that you have described. $SU(2)$ has an algebra $su(2)$ whose representations may act on vector spaces of different dimensions. General $j$ representations are representations of the algebra $su(2)$. I think that clarifies your first question as well.

Comment: This is helpful, but I'm seeking a description of how those vectors (and perhaps the individual components of those vectors) relate to the $\Bbb C \times \Bbb C$ space.

Comment: The column vector that you have written is the most general member of a vector space which is the two dimensional complex vector space. What each component represents depends on what physical system you are considering. One may correspond to the ground state amplitude and the other excited state etc.. $\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{C}$ just means that it is a two dimensional vector space defined over a complex field. The question you are asking is what do the directions in this vector space correspond to? They correspond to some chosen basis vectors in this vector space.

Comment: So, the basis vectors will point along some complex phases and have magnitude 1, and then the components of a vector will act as magnitudes along those phases? (I am realizing now, as CuriousOne pointed out, that this is really a math question about complex vector spaces.)

Comment: You can parameterize your axes any way you want to, but the usual convention is to parameterize them so that projection onto an axis is a **linear** function.  Magnitude is not linear.